# Make a record in one Entity Inactive when a value is changed in another Entity of the same record in crm 2011 on-premise

Tags: workflow, dynamics-crm-2011

I have two entities, Bookings and Discharge.

When a record is created in Bookings, it automatically creates a record in Discharge. Discharge 
has an additional field that is a drop down with four options.

I want a functionality where when any one of the values in drop down is chosen, the similar record in Bookings 
should shift from "Active" view to a default view which I have created by the name of "Processed" in Bookings.

What I have in mind is to create a hidden field in Bookings that is populated when I choose one of the options from Discharge drop down and based on that field the record should shift the view in Bookings. But how do I populate the hidden field? Workflow is not giving me that option or maybe I am doing something wrong.

Help?

So I have created a 1:N relationship between Booking and Discharge. The field is updated in Booking based on the field in Discharge and I choose the particular record in Booking from the look up field in Discharge. But I want to get rid of this second step. I don't want to choose the record in Booking entity but directly update it from Discharge. There are some fields and their values common in both forms, can I create a relationship based on that?

Comment: What dropdown (picklist?) are you talking about? And could you explain more what you mean by *another entity of the same record*? A record to me sounds like an instance of an entity but in that case, one can't have a different entity of the same record, right? Elaborate, please.

Comment: Basically if a person is discharged from the Discharge entity, the related record in Booking entity should shift from Active view to a custom view.

Comment: What I mean by _another entity of the same record?_ is that when a record is created in booking entity, a similar record is created in Discharge entity. When a particular person is discharged from Discharge entity, I want the same persons record to be Inactivated from Booking entity.

Comment: So you want a plugin that runs on the update of Discharge, and, if certain criteria is met, locates the related Booking Entity and changes it's status?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the first part of your question
*"What I have in mind is to create a hidden field in Bookings that is populated when I choose one of the options from Discharge drop down and based on that field the record should shift the view in Bookings. But how do I populate the hidden field?"*

If the field is not on a form you can't set its value hence the following:
I don't believe you can set a hidden field using a workflow. However there is a 'visibility' option on the form designer.

I suggest you add your "hidden" field to the form. Then double click on it and toggle the "Visible by default" checkbox. This will hide the field from the user.

You can then set the value of this field using a workflow.

Regarding part two of your question
*I don't want to choose the record in Booking entity but directly update it from Discharge. There are some fields and their values common in both forms, can I create a relationship based on that*

You have a 1:N relationship however you want to set the related Booking Dynamically is this correct? You cannot select a Booking in the lookup field based on criteria from a workflow. You would need to use a plugin.

If the Discharge has a related Booking (the Booking lookup on Discharge is already set) then you can use a workflow to either:
1) Set a field value (Using 'Update Record' in the Workflow steps) in the parent Booking
2) set to Inactive (Using 'Change Status' in the Workflow steps) in the parent Booking

Comment: I dont want to set a hidden field using a workflow, i want to set its value using workflow but i dont seem to get the option to set its value. I want a field in one entity to set the value of this hidden field which is in another entity.

Comment: And maybe I don't need to update the hidden field....I can just work with when the person is discharged the related record in Bookings should get Inactive. The issue thus is how to relate the two records.